# Error in manifest or policy file(Invalid Xml syntax)

Tags: xml, scheduled-tasks

I have a .net console app which is written in C#, this is supposed to be setup in a task scheduler(as job), I have setup the task with all the requirements(action, triggers, conditions and settings). However when I try to run the job I see an error that reads **The application has failed because of its side-by-side configuration**, when check the event logs I see the error that reads **Invalid Xml syntax**

Below is the screenshot of an error I am seeing on event viewer and the line below that is the actual line(line7 as per the event viewer)
[image: Error from event viewer]
`<connectionStrings>`

I have then since open the config file with notepad++, set the language to xml to see there is anything amiss in the file but there is nothing wrong in as far as I can see

Here is a more detailed config part(in case some asks for it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContextName" connectionString="Data Source=DBServerName;Initial Catalog=Catalogname;User ID=TrafficFinesUser;Password=DbPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What syntax error am  I having here exactly?

Comment: Hi, did you finally solve this?